# Extjs Locking Grid... how to make it appear in a div?

Tags: html, extjs, grid

This seems like a simple enough question, yet I've spent 3 hours and found no information on how to do it. I purchased Ext JS 4, and I'm trying to get the "Locking Grid" to appear on one of my web pages. The grid will be very simple in the end, with no fancy ajax or anything, just a grid to display some info. I went through their quick start tutorial, and it simply tells you to paste some code into a javascript file, and include a ref to that javascript file in the header of your page.

Well, that does nothing. No grid appears. And why would it, I haven't told the grid where to appear. How do you tell the grid to appear in a particular div on my page, or to appear on my page at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use the [renderTo](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-renderTo) config or use the [render](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.util.Renderable-method-render) method. Be sure to read the notes for these, specifically that you should not use render/renderTo on items going inside a container, only top level components.

Comment: I found an example at: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/locking-grid.html, which I was able to view the source and get a clean copy of the code needed to do it. Your answer was right.